# Error in r: "mean" is not a valid subset when averaging over years in a raster

Tags: raster, r, for-loop, average

I am using a moving window average to estimate change between historical climate (here, a 36-year average for a period) and the moving window averages of climate into the future. Each moving window period should start +1 year at each iteration and should be a 36-year average. My raster stack for the "future" period for which moving windows will be calculated looks something like this:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(gdm)

b <- brick(ncol=5, nrow=5, nl=131)
values(b) <- 1:(25*131)
yr<-seq(1970, 2100, 1)
setZ(b, yr)

   class      : RasterBrick
dimensions : 5, 5, 25, 131  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 72, 36  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
source     : memory
names      : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3, layer.4, layer.5, layer.6, layer.7, layer.8, layer.9, layer.10, layer.11, layer.12, layer.13, layer.14, layer.15, ...
min values :       1,      26,      51,      76,     101,     126,     151,     176,     201,      226,      251,      276,      301,      326,      351, ...
max values :      25,      50,      75,     100,     125,     150,     175,     200,     225,      250,      275,      300,      325,      350,      375, ...
time       : 1970, 2100 (min, max)
```

b2 <- brick(ncol=5, nrow=5, nl=131)
values(b2) <- 1

I need to define the starting and ending periods and window lengths for the moving windows:

```
start.year<-1970 
end.year.hist<-2005 #(the last year in the "historical" 36-year period)
end.year.future<-2100
window.length<-end.year.hist-start.year+1 #(+1 to be inclusive of the starting year)
> window.length
[1] 36 #confirm the number of windows to be correct
```

I then define the first period (in other words the historical period that I base the size of my moving window on, which I've called "focal years"):

```
focalYears<-start.year:end.year.hist
> focalYears
 [1] 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984
[16] 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999
[31] 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
```

Based on the the above, this is the number of windows that need to be calculated:

```
num.windows<-end.year.future-end.year.hist
[1] 95
```

And here is my loop:

```
    for(i in 1:length(num.windows)){
      
      futureYears<-focalYears+1 #Define the moving window period as "futureYears", which 
#is the historical window period +1 (i.e. the first iteration should be for 1971 -- 2006)
          
#Make the moving window average for the future (i.e. the mean of the 36-year future window)

      future.Rast.pred<-mean(b[[futureYears]])
      
 

   #Predict function in `gdm`, which uses the historical raster (`current.Rast.mask`) and calculates the change given the future raster, 
#being the moving window average defined above. The historical period raster is simply the average of 1970--2005. 
     

     timePred <- predict(G15.gdm.bio1, data=setNames(b2[[i]],"bio1"), time=TRUE,
                              predRasts=setNames(b[[i]],"bio1"))
      
    rm(timePred)
    }
```

However, I get the error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': not a valid subset
```

What is the issue with how I've tried to subset to calculate the mean period here?

P.S.
However, If I change `focalYears` to `focalYears<-seq(1,36,1)`

```
> focalYears
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
[26] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
```

Then I don't get the error about the mean anymore and the loop does run, but it only iterates once for the first year and then stops.

(P.P.S. `b2` is an historical raster brick which is the average of the historical period for which the gdm results were based on i.e. the 36-year period. The number of layers needs to match the future period, which is why there are 131 despite the historical period only being 36 years.)

```
 > b2
class      : RasterBrick
dimensions : 5, 5, 25, 131  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 72, 36  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
source     : memory
names      : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3, layer.4, layer.5, layer.6, layer.7, layer.8, layer.9, layer.10, layer.11, layer.12, layer.13, layer.14, layer.15, ...
min values :       1,       1,       1,       1,       1,       1,       1,       1,       1,        1,        1,        1,        1,        1,        1, ...
max values :       1,       1,       1,       1,       1,       1,       1,       1,       1,        1,        1,        1,        1,        1,        1, ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code (the loop) does not run and does not show the error. Without that is very difficult to help, but I will try.

The error occurs here

```
future.Rast.mask[[futureYears]]
```

Because you are using years (1970, 1972, 1973, ...) as an index. You would need to have that many (>1970) layers for that to work. It should be an index like (1, 2, 3, 4, ...). That is why it works with `focalYears <-seq(1,36,1)`. If your index goes outside the allowed range you get an error like this

```
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
b[[3:4]]
#Error in .local(x, ...) : not a valid subset
```

The loop running only once is because you do

```
for(i in 1:length(num.windows))
```

The `length` of `num.windows` is 1. You are looking for

```
for(i in 1:num.windows)
```

Comment: Ok sure, will do. I think my loop looks incomplete because I added comments in-between the different parts of the loop. I'll try clarify this question with something reproducible. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help this asker with writing their code snippet.  To avoid flags on your answer (for being Not An Answer; I've already seen one) please try to turn your "long comment in an answer" into an "answer to the question" as soon as you can.

Comment: Once you know how to ask an R question, and take the time to do it, you can answer most of them yourself.

Comment: @RobertHijmans Sorry, of course its not reproducible because I haven't provided the output of G15.gdm.bio1. But, as you point out, the issues were all in the first part of the loop. Thank you, your answer is super helpful.